# Как узнать, подошёл ли указатель к концу массива

Tags: c++, c

Всем добра!

Имеется массив символов `msg` и указатель на него `ptr`. Массив заполняется через указатель. Есть ли какой-то способ узнать, не вышел ли указатель на пределы массива?

```
char msg[256];
char* ptr = msg;

void put_char(char ch) {
    if (is_ptr_out())
        ptr = msg;
    *ptr++ = ch;
}

bool is_ptr_out() {
    bool res = false;
    // if (ptr за пределами массива)
    //    res = true;
    return res;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Уточню вопрос - массив `msg` имеет конкретный размер, а данные могут приходить неизвестного размера, и не обязательно в конце будет символ `\0`. И смысл вопроса - как не залезть за пределы массива, наполняя его данными. К тому же заполняемый массив может иметь другой тип отличный от `char`, например `uint16_t`.

Comment: Сравнивать с заказанным размером. Или использовать что-то типа `vector`, `array`.

Comment: Для нативных массивов ```c``` - только самому так или иначе считать.

Comment: @Harry, а как мне сравнить указатель с размером массива, не пойму? Типа этого: ```ptr >= msg + sizeof(msg)```

Comment: Если вы используете строки в массиве, то признак конца строки это 0. И тогда if (*Ptr == 0) значит конец строки. Если вы сами заполняете массив, то делайте в конце "Hello World\0"

Comment: @FrancNet , я не об этом спрашивал. Уточнил вопрос

Comment: Ну тогда у вас один из вариантов, использовать длину массива. Любые данные куда-то помещаются, и это куда-то имеет размер, в вашем случае msg[256]. sizeof вернет его длину. Но в любом случае, если вы его заполняете сами и не полностью, строками, то ограничитель 0! Это свойство используют и другие функции библиотеки string, к примеру. Т.е они подразумевают что строка заканчивается 0. Программист должен контролировать сам Range. И ставить 0 в конце стринговых данных. Либо переменная count которая для контроля заполняемости используется.

Comment: `if (ptr == (msg + sizeof(msg) / sizeof(*msg))`, легко.

Comment: Это учебная задача или решается какая-то реальная проблема? И не очень понятно как реагировать на одновременное присутствие меток [tag:c] и [tag:c++]. На каком языке требуется решение? На пересечении множеств, чтобы работало и в С, и в С++?

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так, но лучше не изобретайте колесо и используйте std::string

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename charT, size_t N>
class String {
    size_t count;
    charT msg[N + 1];
    charT *ptr, *first, *last;

public:
    String(): count(0) {
        for(size_t i = 0; i <= N; ++i) { msg[i] = '\0'; }
        last = &msg[N];
        first = &msg[0];
        ptr = first - 1;
    }

    bool push_back(charT c) {
        if(count >= N) { return false; }

        ++ptr;
        msg[count++] = c;
        return true;
    }

    bool push_back2(charT c) {
        if(++ptr >= last) { return false; }

        ++count;
        *ptr = c;
        return true;
    }

    charT* get_msg() { return first; }
    size_t lenght() const { return count; }

    charT* end() { return last; }
    charT* begin() { return first; }
};

template<typename charT>
char print(charT* beg, charT* end) {
    for(charT* it = beg; it < end; ++it)
        std::wcout << static_cast<wchar_t>(*it);
    return '\0';
}

int main() {
    //s1
    String<char, 2> s1;

    std::cout << "s1:\n";
    std::cout << s1.push_back2('a') << ' ';
    std::cout << s1.push_back2('b') << ' ';
    std::cout << s1.push_back2('c') << ' ';
    std::cout << s1.push_back2('d') << '\n';

    std::cout << s1.get_msg() << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    // s2
    String<char16_t, 2> s2;

    std::cout << "s2:\n";
    std::cout << s2.push_back2(u'a') << ' ';
    std::cout << s2.push_back2(u'b') << ' ';
    std::cout << s2.push_back2(u'c') << ' ';
    std::cout << s2.push_back2(u'd') << '\n';

    std::cout << print(s2.begin(), s2.end()) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: За ```last = &msg[N];``` спасибо

Comment: @Olejan **И смысл вопроса - как не залезть за пределы массива, наполняя его данными.** Вводите данные пока `push_back` возвращает `true`. **К тому же заполняемый массив может иметь другой тип отличный от char, например uint16t.** Шаблоны в данном случае очень упрощают жизнь...